# How can I check if one ActiveRecord class belongs to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-associations

Given two subclasses of ActiveRecord::Base, how can I implement a function that checks to see if one belongs to the other?

`def ClazzA < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :clazz_b
end`

def ClazzB < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clazz_a
end

def belongs_to? a, b
   ...
end

Thanks!
Max

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  def belongs_to?(a,b)
    sym = b.to_s.downcase.to_sym
    a.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).map(&:name).include?(sym)
  end

> belongs_to?(ClazzA,ClazzB) # true
> belongs_to?(ClazzB,ClazzA) # false
```

Comment: You might want to define this in the model as a class method to make it easier to read, a la:

Clazza.belongs_to?(ClazzB)

Comment: in my controller, I had to change the second line to:
    sym = b.class.name.to_s.downcase.to_sym

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def belongs_to? a, b
  b.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).
    any?{|bta| bta.association_class == a}
end
```

**Note**:

This question was unanswered when I started answering. After completing the answer I noticed the answer posted by @zeteic. I am letting the answer stand as this solution will work even for cases when the association name doesn't map to model name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer KandadaBoggu! Appreciate your clarity.